# как переделать listview?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

У меня есть активити, в нём один recyclerview адаптер. Как всё переделать в **StickyListHeaders** как в примере на [ресурсе](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders)?

вот мой адаптер:

```
public class DirectoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DirectoryAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static int MODE_DIRECTORY = 0;
    private static int MODE_FAVORITES = 1;
    public boolean colorTitleStation = true;

    public interface Listener {
        void onStationClicked(final Station station);
    }

    private final List<Station> stations = new LinkedList<>();
    private Listener listener;
    private int mode;

    public DirectoryAdapter() {
        stations.addAll(getStations());
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.directory_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Station station = stations.get(position);
        holder.nameView.setText(station.getName());
        holder.genre.setText(String.format("Жанр: %s", station.getNetwork()));
        holder.descriptionView.setText(String.format("%s", station.getDescription()));

        Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(station.getIconUrl()).fit().centerCrop().transform(new Transformation() {
            @Override
            public Bitmap transform(final Bitmap source) {
                PaletteCache.generate(station.getIconUrl(), source);
                return source;
            }

            @Override
            public String key() {
                return station.getIconUrl();
            }
        }).into(holder.iconView, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                final Palette palette = PaletteCache.get(station.getIconUrl());
                if (palette == null)
                    return;

                final Palette.Swatch swatch = palette.getVibrantSwatch();
                if (swatch != null) {

                }

                // ставим цвет заголовка названия станций
                if (!colorTitleStation){
                    if (swatch != null) {
                        holder.nameView.setTextColor(swatch.getRgb());
                        colorTitleStation = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    colorTitleStation = true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {

            }
        });

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                if (listener != null)
                    listener.onStationClicked(station);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(final int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return stations.size();
    }

    private List<Station> getStations() {
        if (mode == MODE_FAVORITES) {
            return Favorites.getFavorites();
        }
        return Directory.getStations();
    }

    public void showFavorites() {
        mode = MODE_FAVORITES;
        updateStations();
    }

    public int showDirectory() {return stations.size();}

    public void setListener(final Listener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }


    public void filterStations(final String query) {
        List<Station> filteredStations = queryStations(query);
        updateStations(filteredStations);
    }

    public void updateStations(final List<Station> filteredStations) {
        removeFilteredStations(filteredStations);
        addFilteredStations(filteredStations);
    }

    public void updateStations() {
        updateStations(getStations());
    }

    private void removeFilteredStations(final List<Station> filteredStations) {
        final Iterator<Station> iterator = stations.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            final Station station = iterator.next();
            if (!filteredStations.contains(station)) {
                final int position = stations.indexOf(station);
                iterator.remove();
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
            }
        }
    }

    private void addFilteredStations(final List<Station> filteredStations) {
        for (Station station : filteredStations) {
            if (!stations.contains(station)) {
                final int position = findPosition(station);
                stations.add(position, station);
                notifyItemInserted(position);

            }
        }
    }

    private int findPosition(final Station station) {

        int position = 0;
        while(position < stations.size() && stations.get(position).getName().compareToIgnoreCase(station.getName()) < 0) {
            position++;
        }

        return position;
    }

    private List<Station> queryStations(final String query) {
        final List<Station> filtered = new ArrayList<>();

        final boolean isEmpty = TextUtils.isEmpty(query);
        for (Station station : getStations()) {
            if (isEmpty || station.matchesQuery(query))
                filtered.add(station);
        }
        return filtered;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView iconView;
        TextView nameView, descriptionView, genre;

        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            iconView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            nameView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            descriptionView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            genre = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
        }
    }
}
```

**вот код из активити с нужным мне "адаптером" как я понял:**

```
public class ExpandableListTestActivity extends Activity {

    private ExpandableStickyListHeadersListView mListView;
    TestBaseAdapter mTestBaseAdapter;
    WeakHashMap<View,Integer> mOriginalViewHeightPool = new WeakHashMap<View, Integer>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.expandable_sample);
        mListView = (ExpandableStickyListHeadersListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        //custom expand/collapse animation
        mListView.setAnimExecutor(new AnimationExecutor());
        mTestBaseAdapter = new TestBaseAdapter(this);
        mListView.setAdapter(mTestBaseAdapter);
        mListView.setOnHeaderClickListener(new StickyListHeadersListView.OnHeaderClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onHeaderClick(StickyListHeadersListView l, View header, int itemPosition, long headerId, boolean currentlySticky) {
                if(mListView.isHeaderCollapsed(headerId)){
                    mListView.expand(headerId);
                }else {
                    mListView.collapse(headerId);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    //animation executor
    class AnimationExecutor implements ExpandableStickyListHeadersListView.IAnimationExecutor {

        @Override
        public void executeAnim(final View target, final int animType) {
            if(ExpandableStickyListHeadersListView.ANIMATION_EXPAND==animType&&target.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
                return;
            }
            if(ExpandableStickyListHeadersListView.ANIMATION_COLLAPSE==animType&&target.getVisibility()!=View.VISIBLE){
                return;
            }
            if(mOriginalViewHeightPool.get(target)==null){
                mOriginalViewHeightPool.put(target,target.getHeight());
            }
            final int viewHeight = mOriginalViewHeightPool.get(target);
            float animStartY = animType == ExpandableStickyListHeadersListView.ANIMATION_EXPAND ? 0f : viewHeight;
            float animEndY = animType == ExpandableStickyListHeadersListView.ANIMATION_EXPAND ? viewHeight : 0f;
            final ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = target.getLayoutParams();
            ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(animStartY, animEndY);
            animator.setDuration(200);
            target.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                    if (animType == ExpandableStickyListHeadersListView.ANIMATION_EXPAND) {
                        target.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        target.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    target.getLayoutParams().height = viewHeight;
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

                }
            });
            animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                    lp.height = ((Float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue()).intValue();
                    target.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    target.requestLayout();
                }
            });
            animator.start();

        }
    }
}
```

не совсем пойму, как и что заменить для того чтоб мой список listview был как в примере... Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Собственно, нужно переделать адаптер таким образом, чтобы он наследовал BaseAdapter и отвечал интерфейсу StickyListHeadersAdapter. Как-то так:

```
public class NewDirectoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements StickyListHeadersAdapter {

private static int MODE_DIRECTORY = 0;
private static int MODE_FAVORITES = 1;
public boolean colorTitleStation = true;

public interface Listener {
    void onStationClicked(final Station station);
}

private final List<Station> stations = new LinkedList<>();
private Listener listener;
private int mode;

public NewDirectoryAdapter() {
    stations.addAll(getStations());
}

@Override
public View getHeaderView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    HeaderViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new HeaderViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.header, parent, false);
        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (HeaderViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    //set header text as first char in name
    String headerText = "" + getItem(position).getName().subSequence(0, 1).charAt(0);
    holder.text.setText(headerText);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public long getHeaderId(int position) {
    return getItem(position).getName().subSequence(0, 1).charAt(0);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return stations.size();
}

@Override
public Station getItem(int position) {
    return stations.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.directory_item, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    final Station station = stations.get(position);
    holder.nameView.setText(station.getName());
    holder.genre.setText(String.format("Жанр: %s", station.getNetwork()));
    holder.descriptionView.setText(String.format("%s", station.getDescription()));

    Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(station.getIconUrl()).fit().centerCrop().transform(new Transformation() {
        @Override
        public Bitmap transform(final Bitmap source) {
            PaletteCache.generate(station.getIconUrl(), source);
            return source;
        }

        @Override
        public String key() {
            return station.getIconUrl();
        }
    }).into(holder.iconView, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            final Palette palette = PaletteCache.get(station.getIconUrl());
            if (palette == null)
                return;

            final Palette.Swatch swatch = palette.getVibrantSwatch();
            if (swatch != null) {

            }

            // ставим цвет заголовка названия станций
            if (!colorTitleStation){
                if (swatch != null) {
                    holder.nameView.setTextColor(swatch.getRgb());
                    colorTitleStation = false;
                }
            } else {
                colorTitleStation = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {

        }
    });

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            if (listener != null)
                listener.onStationClicked(station);
        }
    });
}















private List<Station> getStations() {
    if (mode == MODE_FAVORITES) {
        return Favorites.getFavorites();
    }
    return Directory.getStations();
}

public void showFavorites() {
    mode = MODE_FAVORITES;
    updateStations();
}

public int showDirectory() {return stations.size();}

public void setListener(final Listener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}


public void filterStations(final String query) {
    List<Station> filteredStations = queryStations(query);
    updateStations(filteredStations);
}

public void updateStations(final List<Station> filteredStations) {
    removeFilteredStations(filteredStations);
    addFilteredStations(filteredStations);
}

public void updateStations() {
    updateStations(getStations());
}

private void removeFilteredStations(final List<Station> filteredStations) {
    final Iterator<Station> iterator = stations.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        final Station station = iterator.next();
        if (!filteredStations.contains(station)) {
            final int position = stations.indexOf(station);
            iterator.remove();
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }
    }
}

private void addFilteredStations(final List<Station> filteredStations) {
    for (Station station : filteredStations) {
        if (!stations.contains(station)) {
            final int position = findPosition(station);
            stations.add(position, station);
            notifyItemInserted(position);

        }
    }
}

private int findPosition(final Station station) {

    int position = 0;
    while(position < stations.size() && stations.get(position).getName().compareToIgnoreCase(station.getName()) < 0) {
        position++;
    }

    return position;
}

private List<Station> queryStations(final String query) {
    final List<Station> filtered = new ArrayList<>();

    final boolean isEmpty = TextUtils.isEmpty(query);
    for (Station station : getStations()) {
        if (isEmpty || station.matchesQuery(query))
            filtered.add(station);
    }
    return filtered;
}



public static class ViewHolder {
    View itemView;
    ImageView iconView;
    TextView nameView, descriptionView, genre;

    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        this.itemView = itemView;
        iconView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        nameView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        descriptionView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        genre = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
    }
}

public static class HeaderViewHolder {

    private TextView text;
}
}
```

Далее в качестве списка можно использовать StickyListHeadersListView (в примере он) вместо ExpandableStickyListHeadersListView (аналог, позволяющий раскрывать элементы списка). Соответственно, код ExpandableListTestActivity может выглядеть как-то так:

```
public class ExpandableListTestActivity extends Activity {

    private ExpandableStickyListHeadersListView mListView;
    TestBaseAdapter mTestBaseAdapter;
    WeakHashMap<View,Integer> mOriginalViewHeightPool = new WeakHashMap<View, Integer>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.expandable_sample);
        mListView = (ExpandableStickyListHeadersListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        //custom expand/collapse animation
        mListView.setAnimExecutor(new AnimationExecutor());
        mTestBaseAdapter = new TestBaseAdapter(this);
        mListView.setAdapter(mTestBaseAdapter);
    }
}
```